# Array filled in the wrong order

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a strange problem, when I push my result in my array, the result isn't at the right position in my array (for example the result instead of being at the index number 1 is at the index 3), and when I re-run my module results change of position randomly in the array .

```
var cote = function(links, callback) {

  var http = require('http');
  var bl = require('bl');

  var coteArgus = [];

  for (i = 0; i < links.length; i ++) {
    http.get('http://www.website.com/' + links[i], function(response) {

      response.pipe(bl(function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
         callback(err + " erreur");
         return;
        }

        var data = data.toString()

        newcoteArgus = data.substring(data.indexOf('<div class="tx12">') + 85, data.indexOf(';</span>') - 5);
        myresult.push(newcoteArgus);

        callback(myresult);
      }));
    });   
  }
};

exports.cote = cote;
```

Comment: seems it depends from working `$http.get` and when it get response from server for every request

Comment: `Array.push()` always adds to the end of the array. So if the array is not in the order you're expecting, I'd look at the data you're pushing onto the array... that expression you use where you're calling `substring()` and `indexOf()` looks like a possible culprit ... Inspect the value of that expression in the debugger or log it to the console.

Answer (score 5):

The problem lies in the fact that although the `for` is synchronous the `http.get` and the `pipe` operation are not (I/O is async in nodejs) so the order of the array depends on which request and pipe finishes first which is unknown.

Try to avoid making async operations in a loop, instead use libraries like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) for flow control.

Comment: How can I use my loop to do async operations ?  I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done in the right order, using  [async map](https://github.com/caolan/async#maparr-iterator-callback)

Here a sample with map and using [request module](https://github.com/request/request).

```
// There's no need to make requires inside the function,
// is better just one time outside the function.
var request = require("request");
var async = require("async");

var cote = function(links, callback) {

  var coteArgus = [];

  async.map(links, function(link, nextLink) {

    request("http://www.website.com/" + link, function(err, response, body) {
       if (err) {
        // if error so, send to line 28 with a error, exit from loop.
        return nextLink(err);
       }

       var newcoteArgus = body.substring(
        body.indexOf("<div class='tx12'>") + 85,
        body.indexOf(";</span>") - 5
       );
       // pass to next link, and  add newcoteArgus to the final result
       nextLink(null, newcoteArgus);
    });
  },
  function(err, results) {

    // if there's some errors, so call with error
    if(err) return callback(err);

    // there's no errors so get results as second arg
    callback(null, results);
  });

};

exports.cote = cote;
```

One more thing, i'm not sure, really what you are doing in the part where  you search html content in the responses  [but there's a really good library to work with JQuery selectors from server side](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) maybe can be useful for you.

Here's how you should call the function

```
// Call function sample.
var thelinks = ["features", "how-it-works"];

cote(thelinks, function(err, data) {

  if(err) return console.log("Error: ",  err);
  console.log("data --> ", data);

});
```

Comment: It doesn't need to be `mapSeries` or `eachSeries`. __map__ and __each__ will work just fine. If you run it in series it's sequential meaning that each request will wait for the previous one to complete. but the order of the `result` will be the same with `map` and `mapSeries` being the latter significantly slower.

Comment: Your fonction doesn't work it return null and the research for html doesn't work also, http.get() seams to be better.

Comment: @Maroshii Sorry if i'm wrong but i think if you not wait in each loop to the request is completed, you can't guarantee the order of the result array, so if you use each or map the array will continue filling in any order.  take a look to this description https://github.com/caolan/async#collections-1   -  Read the Note, that since this function applies iterator to each item in parallel, there is no guarantee that the iterator functions will complete in order.

Comment: @Peter i fixed a little problem in the function,  try again please.

Comment: @GonzaloBahamondez. It runs in parallel and the order of completion is not guaranteed but the order of the result is. From the docs: __"... However, the results array will be in the same order as the original array."__

Comment: @Maroshii , ok you have reason about ***map*** sorry about  my error,  i edited my code,  just one more thing,  you mentioned this is possible too with each, but i can't find a way to keep the order using just ***each***

Comment: __each__ doesn't pass any values to the callback function, just the error (if any) whereas __map__ does, that's the only difference.
I think you are confusing order of execution with the order of the values that are passed on to the completion callback. __eachSeries__ differs from __each__ in that the _next_ callback from, say, index 0 is ALWAYS called before index 1. That has nothing to do with the order of the array. Note that _series_ is MUCH slower since they wait for each other.

Comment: So, there's no way to do just with each?